# SQL uso do LEFT JOIN com OR

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sou novo com o `SQL`  e  tenho a seguinte dúvida relativa ao `LEFT JOIN`: tenho que relacionar uma tabela de `cliente` onde cada cliente possui um *id* e um *código* de cliente com outra tabela que contém os endereços; em alguns caso o cliente possui *id*, em outros, ele possui o *código*.

tentei utilizando a consulta abaixo, porém não sei se é a melhor escolha ou se está correto.

```
SELECT cli.clicod, cli.atlcod, clinompessoa, grade.camnum 
FROM cli
LEFT JOIN codEnd on cli.clicod = codEnd.clicod 
LEFT JOIN grade on cli.clicod = grade.clicod or cli.atlcod = grade.atlcod
WHERE logcod = 32388
  AND camnum = 520
```

tabelas resumidas basicamente eu quero pegar os clientes que pertence as ruas  que possuem a campanha 520, as planilhas são antigas sem a possibilidade de normalização dos dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mateus, para conseguirmos auxiliar seria necessário você postar a estrutura das tabelas que estão sendo utilizadas na sua instrução SQL

Comment: @MateusSilva Utiliza-se LEFT JOIN quando a junção não é obrigatória.

Comment: Pelo que vejo o código está correto. O `LEFT JOIN` deve ser utilizado quando eventualmente não existir correspondência na 2ª tabela. Caso exista sempre correspondência, podemos utilizar o `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Será que `LEFT JOIN` é o ideal? entendendo que ele vai alinhas as colunas da esquerda sempre e se houver então as da direita, caso queira obrigatoriedade no resultado, não seria mais apropriado um `INNER JOIN`? Em todo o caso, tua consulta retorna o que deseja? Caso sim então a pergunta seria referente a otimização desta consulta e não se ela esta correta, sugiro fazer alguns testes em situações ideais e inusitadas para verificar se tudo ocorre bem.

Comment: Aparentemente está correto. O que tem que ver é: será que o relacionamento de "cli" com "codEnd" não ocorrerá sempre, se isso sempre ocorrer o recomendado é utilizar o "INNER JOIN". Sobre o LEFT JOIN com "or" você pode fazer um teste e medir o desempenho, desenvolver 2 consultas com as condições que colocou no relacionamento da tabela "grade" utilizando INNER JOIN. Nesse caso, você utilizaria UNION para relacionar suas 2 consultas. A outra possível solução mais simples, utilizando "IN" não recomendo, costuma ser mais lento que utilizar "LEFT JOIN".

Comment: Eu entendi que o OP está querendo OU utilizar o código quando existir OU utilizar o id como chave do join caso o código não exista. É isso o que você espera @Mateus?

Comment: ngueno isso que eu quero

Comment: basicamente sao 3 tabelas antigas

Answer (score 1):

Dependendo do objetivo, a consulta pode ter `LEFT JOIN` ou `INNER JOIN`.

Se o que pretende é obter os resultados ligando diretamente as 3 tabelas, onde um registo da tabela `cli` existe **obrigatoriamente** em 1 ou mais registos  na tabela `codEnd` e `grade`, então deverá utilizar o `INNER JOIN` com um `OR` na junção, de forma a ligar por uma ou outra coluna:

```
SELECT      C.clicod
        ,   C.atlcod
        ,   C.clinompessoa
        ,   G.camnum 
FROM        cli     C
INNER JOIN  codEnd  CE  ON  C.clicod = CE.clicod
                        OR  C.atlcod = CE.atlcod
INNER JOIN  grade   G   ON  C.clicod = G.clicod 
                        OR  C.atlcod = G.atlcod
WHERE       logcod = 32388
        AND camnum = 520
```

---

Caso queira obter resultados da tabela `cli`, mas não sabe se existe ligação direta ou simplesmente a tabela `cli` tem um relacionamento de **0:N** (0 para N) ou **0:1** (0 para 1) com as outras tabelas, então deve utilizar o `LEFT JOIN` para evitar restringir a consulta indevidamente:

```
SELECT      C.clicod
        ,   C.atlcod
        ,   C.clinompessoa
        ,   G.camnum 
FROM        cli     C
LEFT JOIN   codEnd  CE  ON  C.clicod = CE.clicod
                        OR  C.atlcod = CE.atlcod
LEFT JOIN   grade   G   ON  C.clicod = G.clicod 
                        OR  C.atlcod = G.atlcod
WHERE       logcod = 32388
        AND camnum = 520
```

Esta 2ª opção é mais segura quando não temos a certeza do que está na tabelas relacionadas.

---

**Atenção** que em ambos os casos podemos ter duplicados devido ao `JOIN` entre várias tabelas, principalmente quando a relação é **0:N** ou **1:N**.